# ,join 2 tables and display the count of particular column

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables in my db..one is hr_request_consultant
and another one is hr_request_candidate

1)hr_request_consultant:

id,
hr_request_id,
consultant_id.

2)hr_request_candidate:
id,
hr_request_id,
candidate_id.

so i want to join these 2 tables and count the candidates of that particular hr_request_id in hr_request_consultant table

Can anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.hr_request_id, count(b.candidate_id)
from hr_request_consultant a
inner join hr_request_candidate b
on a.hr_request_id = b.hr_request_id
group by a.hr_request_id
```

I think should do the job?

Comment: i got error Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'b.hr_request_candidate' in 'field list'

Comment: Modified and fixed. Did you really down vote me? That's pretty poor form...

Comment: it displaying double values...for example if it is 3 it displaying 6

Comment: Can you provide at least a minimum viable example of your data sets? If the data was logically structured, I would expect my code to have already worked, so there may be replication of rows potentially.

Comment: INSERT INTO `hr_request_consultant` (`id`, `hr_request_id`, `consultant_id`) VALUES
(7, 24, 2),
(6, 24, 3),
(3, 24, 4),
(8, 24, 7),
(4, 28, 4),
(5, 29, 4),
(2, 29, 8);

Comment: INSERT INTO `hr_request_candidate` (`id`, `hr_request_id`, `candidate_id`, `hr_request_status_id`, `interview_type_id`, `interview_datetime`, `feedback`, `is_active`, `created_on`, `modified_on`, `created_by`, `modified_by`) VALUES
(1, 29, 2, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, 29, 16, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(5, 29, 18, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, 24, 1, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, 24, 20, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),

Comment: these are my table content..so for example take 29 ..29 have 3 candidates in hr_request_candidate...so when i select 29 it display only 3

Comment: Right. So the problem is for `hr_request_id=29`, you have `consultant_id=4` and `consultant_id=8`. That is why you get a factor of 6 rather than 3. It's somewhat unclear to me what you want, but I would hope the code I gave you above is enough of a base case to be able to modify into a working query.

What is the difference between `hr_request_id` and `consultant_id`?